# Why is my div height spacing not consistent in it's container?

Tags: css, shiny

I have a container with two divs and I can't understand why the first div (div_in_topl) is dropping down.  Before I added CSS there was no space above "Select time period to view" and all was in perfect alignment.
[image: screen shot from R STudio]

CSS:

```
.header_container{
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  background-color: #FFE6E6;
  margin: 0 0 20px 60px;
}
.div_in_topl {
display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.div_in_topr {
display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
.header_container{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```